# How to importing python packages from inside a docker container from mounted disk without copying them?

Tags: import, directory, dockerfile, python-3.8

So, I am trying to run a python program on docker container, which will pick packages from mounted disk.

For this I have created a virtual machine i.e. ubuntu linux.
The python version = 3.8.18

First I installed all the required packages to a target location, zipped it and copied and extracted it in virtual machine.

I add the mounted path in system using below line of code,
**sys.path.append('/mnt/testPackages')**

After this I created the docker image of the repo using below dockerfile statements,

FROM python:3.8
USER root
COPY opt /opt
COPY sbin /sbin
WORKDIR /opt
ENTRYPOINT ["python3", "srl_functions.py"]

after creation of docker image, I am using below command to run the docker container with mounting the disk,
**docker run -v /home/karan/Downloads:/mnt/ container_id**

I am able to list the contents present in the mounted testPackages directory, but it is keeps on throwing the error that **"module not found"** when it is exist in mounted disk.